# Optics - Object between two “parallel plane mirrors”

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

The problem is the question 5.67 of Hecht book - Optics
[image]

Suppose two mirrors (A and B) are 25 cm apart and a small candle is placed in between them such that you
cannot see it. You see the images at $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{3}$, and they seem to be $10$
cm apart. Where is the candle located?

But in optics textbook by S. Parkinson
published in 1884. he proves that $\overline{Q_{1}Q_{3}} = 2\overline{AB}$
[image]

[image]

and then, $\overline{QQ_{3}} - \overline{QQ_{1}} = 2c = 2\overline{AB} $.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be for a candle in the middle of the two mirrors.

Think about it: if the candle would be right next to $B$, then both $Q1$ and $Q3$ would need to be basically on top of each other, the rays come from almost the same place for both those images, their distance would only be (...answer here...) (and as $QB$ is very small, so is the separation, I had posted the answer before, but changed it so that you figure it out!!).

I don't want to give the real answer. Just want to point out that the answer you posted seems to be for the case where the candle is dead-center.

As a tip, to solve this problem in an intuitive way, without needing geometry, imagine you move the candle from being right at $A$, slowly, all the way back to $B$. Pay attention to the positions of $Q$, $Q1$ and $Q3$. How do they all move? What can you then infer about their positions?

Comment: I considered the reflection in the other mirror, and found a possible answer, namely AQ = 20, because for me Q1Q3 will always be 2 (a + b), regardless of the position of B in relation to the mirror. Am I right?

Comment: Yes the answer is AQ=20, but then you are saying that Q1Q3 will be 2(a+b)=50 in the original problem. But it is stated that Q1Q3=10. So I have no clue how you got 20 from the supposition that Q1Q3 can never be 10cm (it would always be 50) like it was stated in the original problem. Like I said, the 2(a+b) is the solution to the candle dead center. Draw a diagram for the candle Q at the mirror A. Now draw a diagram of the candle Q next to the mirror B. What is the distance AQ1 for both cases? Simpler, what is the distance AQ3 in both cases?

Comment: (1/2) Actually I am not sure the solution of the problem by parkinson is correct. It is very simple: you put Q at A, then Q1 appears right next to the mirror, so Q1A=QA, or Q1Q=2a. You put Q at B, and the candle appears at the boundary condition for Q1 at Q1A=c. The boundary conditions for Q1Q are from 0 to 2c and the distance QQ1=2a. Now with Q at B, Q3 will appear at minimum boundary condition for Q3: same as maximum for Q1, boundary is at A+c. This means distance QQ3=2c. Now Q at A means Q3 is at maximum boundary condition for Q3 at A+2c.

Comment: (2/2) When Q is at A, then QQ3=2c. As you see, with Q at both boundaries, A or B, the distance QQ3=2c. The general condition for $QQ_{2n+1}=2nc$, regardless of the position of Q. Now you can see that QQ3-QQ1=2c-2a=2b. So for the original problem, as QQ3-QQ1=10; 2b=10; b=QB=5-> a=QA=20.

Comment: My teacher put to the test a question similar to this (same drawing), however instead of Q1Q3 = 10 we had that the distance between the last two images in the right mirror was equal to 10, hence my idea of ​​considering two reflections.

Comment: answering your question: in the first case (candle Q in mirror A) we have AQ1 = 0 (because the candle is practically inside the mirror, so your image is in the same position as A), but this image will be seen as an object by the mirror on the right , which will form a new image at Q2 = b (in relation to mirror B), but that image will be seen as an object by the left mirror, so AQ3 = 2b = 50. In the other case, AQ3 = 3b and AQ1 = b